# Issue With Factorial Function

Tags: f#, factorial

I have been trying to write a program which prints out a factorial without actually using recursion.

Here is the code

```
let factorial x = 
   let mutable n = x
       while n > 0 do
             let result = n*(n-1)
             n <- (n-1)
       result
```

The issue is that when I try to run the code it tells me that the expected result is a unit, whereas the input is clearly an integer, which obviously results in an error. However, I have checked all my variables and the compiler interprets them as integers, so what is the issue

Comment: As is the code don't even compile for me (the while "block" is indented too much)

Comment: Your sample is not compiling

Comment: Do you got the answer to your question?

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your code here, you must keep in mind **indentation** in f# is very important, for you want to do your code should be:

```
let factorial x =
   let mutable n = x
   let mutable result = 1
   while n > 0 do
       result <- n * (n-1)
       n <- (n - 1)
   result
```

You were declaring the `result` variable inside the `while` scope and returning it outside it. Your code however is incorrect, I took the liberty of modify it, here what I did:

```
let factorial x =
    let mutable n = x
    let mutable result = 1
    while n >= 1 do
       result <- result * n
       n <- (n - 1)
    result
```

Comment: without decrementing n this is a nice infinite loop ;)

Comment: And even with decrementing n the result only uses the last two numbers; that's not a factorial.

Comment: oops, editing it right now, sorry, must have missed that, thanks @Sehnsucht